# joomla! migration

Tags: joomla

I have a *Joomla!* installation on a remote site and I want to run it locally. I'm running *Joomla!*  locally on a Mac through a standard MAMP installation:

- Joomla 1.5.12
- PHP 5.2.6
- MySQL 5.0.41
- Apache 2.0.59
- OS X 10.5.8

I've added a configuration file to the local *Joomla!* directory with all the correct local settings, database name, database user-name, database password etc. etc.  I've tried a lot of different settings.

I've also recreated the remote database locally, ensuring everything copied correctly.

I followed a few different sets of instructions with roughly the same steps on how to do the migration.  I've also tried increasing the allocated PHP memory.

All of the above has not worked for me; at best I get bits of text from the site rendered in the browser.  Other times I get *SQL* errors.

What I want is for an already set up remote *Joomla!* installation to run on my own local machine.

There's a log dump [here](http://yeeday.net/php_error.txt).

Does anyone have any advice as to how to get this working, it'd be very much appreciated?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Migrating a site should  ;o) be a relatively simple process.

Take a dump of the database, take all of the webfiles.

Place the webfiles on the server

Load the database

Reconfigure the configuration file.

Looking at the dump though, it looks like you might have some whitespace at the top of your configuration.php file. Try removing that.

Comment: Akeeba backup is far simpler and faster.

Answer (score 3):

You may use [akeeba backup](https://www.akeebabackup.com/download.html) for setting up remote site to your localhost.

you have to follow these steps:

--> Go to live site's backend and install akeeba backup (Must be compitible with your Joomla Version).

--> Got to "Configurations" of akeeba and set backup format to .zip

--> Now create backup form "Backup Now".

--> Go to "Administer backup Files" and download backup to your system.

--> Now Extract .zip file to your locahost directory.

--> Open Browser and navigate to the folder(in which backup was extracted).

--> You will see a restoration installer and then follow the steps.

Hope Your site will gets restored successfully.

Answer (score 2):

install a component mtwmigrator  on new joomla site ,where you want to migrated data.
Then in configuration tab, write database configuration i.e. database name which you want to migrate on new site.
It will work for you ,b'coz it works for me

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend against installing third party components. You will waste time trying to fix their problems; instead, go on the server and install a fresh new copy of Joomla. When that is working, go in the configuration file and change it to your database. When your content shows up, overwrite all the files except `configuration.php` and `.htaccess` with the ones from your local server. That way you will find the problem while you are getting it working.

Comment: This should perhaps have been a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).

Answer (score 1):

Use akeeba backup: it's a step by step procedure to easily backup your website and to restore it in another place

Comment: I agree, Akeeba Backup is the quickest easiest way of migrating the Joomla site to a new server, and you will have the least amount of configurations issues when using it.